# HTML to PDF generator generates different size pdf in different devices

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, pdf-generation

I am currently working on an ionic-angular project where users will fill the form and it will generate a pdf with 10-12 pages. I have designed the pdf in html and i use some external library to generate pdf from html.

Unfortunately the fonts and images of the pdf are in different sizes when generated from different devices. I have tried various libraries and still the result seems to be same.

Is there anyway i could do this by updating my html and css? Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try style with `@media print`

Comment: you can use server side to generate PDF. take your user data to your server and generate PDF from server with same design for all devices.